# Haml Form Not Submitting in Sinatra App

Tags: sinatra, haml

I'm having problems submitting my form now that I've converted from erb to haml in a simple sinatra app.

new.haml

```
%form{ :action => "/new", :method => "post"}
  %fieldset
    %ol
      %li
        %label{:for => "username"} Name:
        %input{:type => "text", :username => "name", :class => "text"}
    %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Send", :class => "button"}
```

In my app.rb

```
get '/new' do
    haml :new
end

post '/new' do
  radcheck = Radcheck.new(:username => params[:username])
  if radcheck.save
    redirect '/'
  else
      "Hello World" 
  end
end
```

each time I get the Hello World statement appear. My logs show nothing interesting.

Any ideas? Worked just fine with erb??

Comment: Have you pasted this correctly? Shouldn't `:username => "name"` be the other way around?

Comment: @Slartibartfast - I have also tried %input{:type => "textbox", :username => "username", :id => "username"} without success :(

Comment: Have you tried `:name => "username"`?

Comment: @Slartibartfast not working either, still doesn't save. Do I need to adjust my action?

Comment: Note that when using Haml you can use the [HTML-style attributes](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#attributes) for simplicity, e.g. `%form(action="new" method="post")` or `%label(for="username)`; the benefit of using Ruby hashes is only there when you need to use complex Ruby expressions for the values; otherwise, it's just more typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I've tested

```
get '/new' do
    haml :new
end

post '/new' do
    #radcheck = Radcheck.new(:username => params[:username])
    username = params[:username]
    if username
        username
    else
        "Hello World" 
    end
end
```

and new.haml

```
%form{ :action => "/new", :method => "post"}
  %fieldset
    %ol
      %li
        %label{:for => "username"} Name:
        %input{:type => "text", :name => "username", :class => "text"}
    %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Send", :class => "button"}
```

And it works as expected. So for some reason `radcheck.save` is returning false, but that has nothing to do with haml. (But notice that I have corrected input with `:name => "username"`)

Comment: Hi, that submits the form now and displays value of username but doesn't save to db? Why would that be?

Comment: Because I haven't called `save` I just wanted to check whether post works. Why `radcheck.save` in you code returns false is something I cant answer if you don't provide more details about that part of code, but form submitting (your original question) works as intended.